# TypeError: $ is not a function when calling imgPreload function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem when calling a javascript function. this is my piece of code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/'?>js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/'?>js/imgPreload.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
     $('img').imgPreload()
})
</script>
```

But the result is always "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).imgPreload is not a function". Why it happened?

Note : I'm using ubuntu. i dont know it happened because file permission problem. But i think it's not the reason

Comment: This suggests that either the function name is incorrect or the library didn't load.  Check the network tab in your browser's debugging tools.  Did `imgPreload.js` actually get loaded?

Comment: Based on [this](http://www.farinspace.com/jquery-image-preload-plugin/) I believe the problem is that the function name is supposed to be in all lower case ... try $('img').imgpreload()

Comment: are you loading `jquery-1.9.0.min.js` and `imgPreload.js` correctly?

Comment: in browser's debugging tools, my imgPreload.js is loaded. and jquery-1.9.0.min.js loaded without doubt.

Comment: are you sure the function `imgPreload()` exists?

Comment: sure. i got from this tutorial : http://denysonique.github.io/imgPreload/

Comment: see if it works if you substitute jQuery for $

Comment: It definitely should be lower case function call: `.imgpreload()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know witch version of imgPreload are you using, but usually imgpreload function has all chars lower.
Try to check into your "imgPreload.js" file the correct name of that function.

If I'm right you should only change:

```
$(function(){
     $('img').imgPreload()
})
```

to

```
$(function(){
     $('img').imgpreload()
})
```

Comment: Try to add at least an img on your page ;)

Comment: @dionajie, "imgPreload.js" file is in the same directory of "jquery-1.9.0.min.js" file?

Comment: there is some images on my page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 
last try:

Replace all $ with jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/'?>js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/'?>js/imgPreload.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('img').imgPreload();
})
</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry @dionajie but I can't help anymore. :(